# Asterisk in a minipage

Tags: tables, minipage

How can I include the asterisk symbol (*) in a note in a minipage? When I compile this, it appears as question marks (???) in my pdf. I don't think this is the same issue as an asterisk not appearing in a footnote or table note...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[tbp]
        \centering
        \caption{Effects of Prior Beliefs and Signals on Learning}
        \label{tab:learning_table}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc} \hline
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
            \bigskip
            {\footnotesize Note: * p$<$0.1; ∗∗ p$<$0.05; ∗∗∗ p$<$0.10\par}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your probblem is not related to tables and minipages but to used encoding. try to compile with`xelatex`.

Comment: off-topic: for notes below table is better to use `\multicolumn` cell as the last table row or use `threeparttable` or `threparttablex` with `tablenotes`.

Comment: your asterisks are different after the first use. they even look different in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a tex error, you should ask about that, the output after an error is not usually sensible.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∗ (U+2217)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

You could declare a definition for U+2217 but simpler would be to use the ASCII `*`

If you want a non-raised `*` you can use `\textasteriskcentered`